# Android biometrics login add additional non controlable text

Tags: java, android, biometrics, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I found out strange behaviour of **Android Biometrics Login dialog**. Android add additional text (which I don't even have in my app strings) which I cannot change. As you see on picture below when I try login to app using biometrics, there is one single text in english ("*Touch the fingerprint sensor*") while all app is in polish. It only happens when App Language != Device Language. In that case Android get that text matches the device language.

I checked it and it's not really problem of my app but I see that problem in every other app with biometrics login (part of them use device language for all that login dialog and rest app is in language I setup). There is an option to control it or remove?

OS version: Android 13
Phone: Pixel 6a

[image]

P.S. sorry for big bad quality picture but on Login View screenshoots doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> There is an option to control it or remove?

No, at least on older versions of Android. On Android 13 and higher, you could try switching to [official app-specific language support](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages) and see if that helps at least get the proper translation in there.